# Is there a way to have Parcel inline my Vue SFC CSS into a style tag in the html head?

Tags: css, vue.js, google-apps-script, build, parceljs

I am using Google Apps Script and Google Sites to serve a web-app and I would like to take full advantage of the Vue Single File Components. However, in order to use CSS stylesheets you need/ to inline them.

Normally with a hand crafted CSS file I inline it as follows in the head tag of the html template:

```html
<style>
 @import './style.css'
</style>
```

*With a minimal Vue application, (single component with a p tag and a style setting the text colour to red)

When I run a `parcel build ./index.html` it creates the HTML with the JS file, but a separate CSS file is also created and not in-lined.

Can I get Parcel to inline the separate CSS file into the head of the HTML file?